# Tridion Word Count and Reporting

Tags: powertools

We are starting to work on Reporting in Tridion.
One of the first questions that we would like to answer is the total number of words in a publication in Tridion.

Does anyone has a Powertool or similar tool providing the number of words in components in Tridion? Ideally, published words :-)

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, nothing like that is available in the community (others may correct me). You can try to implement and share to the community :)

Comment: If you do decide to build an extension we'd love to have you build it using the Alchemy framework for Tridion. You can check it out here: http://alchemywebstore.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing out of the box but I can see how this would be useful - particularly if you're considering translation costs etc. (World Server will give word counts etc. but only after content is submitted into its workflow).

You could take a look at (and build your plugin based on) the Find and Replace tool that exists already. http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/555e2ed73913f516a090e5cd

You'll need to consider counting only words and not HTML in RTF fields etc. something that the Find and Replace tool handles already.

Comment: The idea goes beyond translation cost calculation. Like, how many words do you change a week/ month/ year what man power it is invovled in chaning those volumes, how effective is that, should you hire more people, simplify implementation, train your CMers, do you need editorial tools to improve efficiency and can the cost of those  tools be justified by the volume of changes. ... It is time we leave Plato's Cave and join the data driven world!!

Comment: +1 - great points indeed Manuel. I'd used this example as it was hot on my desk at the very moment of writing. Sounds like some great analytical opportunities - would make a great blog post :)